# Listing basic Images in Amazon EC2

Tags: .net, sdk, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Im using .net SDK in amazon ec2.
I would like to know how will I filter and list only the images in **Quick Start.**

Heres what i did so far but still give lots of filter result.

```
DescribeImagesRequest imagesRequest = new DescribeImagesRequest();

var ec2ami = imagesRequest.WithFilter(new Filter().WithName("image type").WithValue("machine").WithName("root-device type").WithValue("ebs")).WithOwner("amazon");

DescribeImagesResponse ec22response = ec2.DescribeImages(ec2ami);        
var listOfAMI = ec22response.DescribeImagesResult.Image;
```

I have tried some supported filters and still I have no idea how to show images only in the Quick Start.

Thanks. Help would be much appreciated.